# How to fetch names using RegEx for given pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to fetch below patterns from the text using RegEx:

```
John Doe
JOHN DOE
Sam John Watson
Sam John Lilly Watson
SAM JOHN WATSON
SAM JOHN LILLY WATSON
```

Input Data only contains single line and I need to find above patterns in that.

**More about Pattern**

- Each word will start with a Uppercase letter and followed by either Upper or Lowercase
- Minimum 2 words
- Maximum 4 words
- Words will include only A-Z or a-z chars

What I Tried:

```
import re
re.findall("[A-Z][A-Za-z]+ [A-Z][A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*", text)
```

Which will correctly identifies input like:

```
Sam Peters John Doe
SAM WINCH DAN BROWN
```

but fails on input with less than 4 words.

Comment: If this is for a real system rather than a programming exercise, it is probably worth reading [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is failing because even with the `*`s after the last two character sets, the spaces next to those last two character sets are *not* optional. So (for example) having only 2 words in the string would only match if those two words were followed by *two spaces*.

I'd suggest that you start with `[A-Z][A-Za-z]+` for the first word, then repeat a space followed by a word up to 3 times:

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Z][A-Za-z]+){1,3}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/IvSvAH/1

If there may be words with only one character (like "I" or "A"), then repeat the `[A-Za-z]` character sets with `*` instead of `+`.

Comment: works like a charm. It would be more helpful if you point out why my solution failed in this case.

Comment: @Sociopath I might also suggest a new username.  But +1 to this answer.